# Why this animation doesnt play?

Tags: html, css, animation

I tried to animate fa icon, but this icon doesnt play animation. I combined with putting this icon into a div, but it still doesnt work.
CSS:

```
.fa-chevron-down{
      animation-name: appear 5s infinite;
      animation-delay: 0s;
      animation-duration: 10s;
      text-shadow: none; 
      transition: 0s; 
   }
@keyframes
        bottomArrow {
       from {
          transform: translateY(-45%);
          opacity: 0;
          filter: blur(5px);
       }
       50% {
          opacity: 1;
          transform: translateY(-45%);
          filter: none;
       }
       100% {
          transform: translateY(50%);
          opacity: 0;
          filter: blur(5px);
       }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="bottombar">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
    <p>Some text</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: because your animation name is "bottomArrow" but in animation-name you wrote "appear".change it to "bottomArrow"

Comment: Also you might consider only putting the animation name as the `animation-name` instead of also including the duration and iteration count.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to include the name of your animation (appears) right after @keyframes.

```
@keyframes appears { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Writing the name of animation behind the sentence @keyframes work. I had three names of animations, so my css code was reading only first anim.

Comment: wrong, the animation won't work unless he corrects this: `animation-name: appear 5s infinite;` this property if for name only it's not the `animation` shorthand

Comment: You're right...I wanted to remove my answer because I tested my own suggestion and it didn't work. Sorry for misinformation

Answer (score 0):

`animation-name` is used to specify a name for the `@keyframes` animation.
So both `animation-name` and the name right after `@keyframes` must match.

```
 <style>
    .fa-chevron-down {
     animation-name: bottomArrow;
     animation-duration: 10s;
     animation-delay: 0s;
     text-shadow: none;
     transition: 0s;
    }

    @keyframes bottomArrow {
     from {
        transform: translateY(-45%);
        opacity: 0;
        filter: blur(5px);
     }
     50% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(-45%);
        filter: none;
     }
     100% {
        transform: translateY(50%);
        opacity: 0;
        filter: blur(5px);
     }
    }
 </style>
```

also if you want to use a shorthand notation like you did above then you can use.

```
   animation: name duration timing-function delay etc..;
```